Spectrum of the out-degree Laplacian matrix
Let $G(V,E)$ be a directed graph with $n$ Vertices and $m$ directed edges $e_{ij}$. Edges indicate there is a link from the $j$th node to the $i$th node. Let $a_{ij}$ be the entries of an adjacency matrix $A$ associated with the digraph $G$. No self-loops are allowed so $a_{ii}=0$ for all $i=\{1,\cdots,n\}$
The out-degree Laplacian matrix is given by $L_o = D_o-A$ where $D_o=diag\{d_1,\cdots,d_n\}$ where $d_i$ is the out-degree of each node $d_i=\sum_p{a_{pi}}$.
Can we relate the spectra of $L_o$ with the graph $G$ similar to a standard Laplacian matrix?
